# Multiple where clause in firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So this is the situation.

I have a database which has a Users collection. In some users I have a `userType` property, but some users don't have this property. `userType` can be equal to both `person` and `company`. How can I pick only the users that have the `userType` property? I could do something like this:

```
let persons = await admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('userType').equalTo('person').once('value');
persons = await persons.val();

let companys = await admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('userType').equalTo('company').once('value');
companys = await companys.val();

let users = persons + companys;
```

but this is just ugly. How can I filter this using a firebase query?

I found this answer [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase) but it's from 2014, so I hoped that maybe some improvement was made in 4 years.

Comment: The answer you found it still correct. You will have to ensure that each user has a value for the `userType` property, since Firebase can't filter for the absence of a property. For example, use a value `none` for the users without a type. Then you can combine the two values you want to filter on into a single property `"company_userType": "company_person"` and filter on that as shown in my linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

The improvement that's been made is the release of Cloud Firestore as an alternative to the Realtime Database. Firestore supports a range of simple and compound queries in a more logical way.

`usersRef.whereEqualTo("userType", "person").whereEqualTo("userType", "company")`

That being said performing an `OR` query still requires you to merge the two results like you have done above.

If that doesn't work for you it may be worth looking at a search indexer like Algolia, as recommended by Firebase.

Comment: I cannot switch to firestore, I have to user the realtime database

Comment: I am using firestore. How can we use where conditions in this situation - fetch all the chat conversations where "(senderid == loggedinuserid and receiverid == 10) or (senderid == 10 and receiverid == loggedinuserid)"? kindly suggest. Thanks.